# How far apart should I space Thuja 'Green Giant' evergreen trees?

Tags: trees, tree-care, planting, evergreens, conifers

If I wanted to plant several Thuja plicata x standishii 'Green Giant', how far apart should they be placed, or does it matter?

Some evergreens seem to like being planted close together (and growing into each other), some seem to like being planted far apart and don't do well together, and some don't seem to care at all. With 'Green Giant', what is the best spacing?

Comment: RE: Your edit: Does this mean that all "Green Giant's" are Thuja pliata x standishii? I was under the impression that there were multiple plants with a similar name (or maybe different subspecies of the same plant)?

Comment: Yes, the real 'Green Giant' is *Thuja plicata x standishii*. Other plants have been called this, even leyland cypresses, but there really is only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plant them 5-7' apart for a privacy screen, 15-20' apart otherwise. These trees mature at 35-60' tall and up to 15' wide.

I you want a screen, you may like the result even better if you stagger the trees, rather than planting them in a straight row.

Answer (score 3):

Minimum 12'-15' apart will reward all of us in the years to come, you and your neighbor as well. Green Giant are beautiful, deer resistant evergreens and very fast growing.

Green Giant Arborvitae can create beautiful screens when planted responsibly and this is all about the spacing. No closer than 12' apart.